# Protected methods in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

What is the equivalent to protected methods in Objective-C?
I want to define methods which only the derived classes may call/implement.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> You can neither declare a method protected *or* private. Objective-C's dynamic nature makes it impossible to implement access controls for methods. (You could do it by heavily
>   modifying the compiler or runtime, at a severe speed penalty, but for obvious reasons this is not done.)

Taken from [Source](http://web.archive.org/web/20120623051136/http://objectmix.com/c/177901-methods-access-modifiers-objective-c.html).

Comment: WHile technically you can't, you can emulate private variables.

Comment: Lee - if you declare a function pointer in @protected and assign a function in init method would it work?

Answer (score 157):

You can **simulate** protected and private access to methods by doing the following:

- Declare your private methods in a class extension (i.e. a unnamed category declared near the top of the class' .m file)
- Declare your protected methods in a Subclass header – Apple uses this pattern with respect to UIGestureRecognizer (see documentation and reference to UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h)

These protections are not, as Sachin noted, enforced at runtime (as they are in Java, for example).

Comment: About the UIGestureRecognizer-like solution: The problem is that if some code imports the subclass it will also import the Subclass header and it will therefore have access to the "protected" methods. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Hi yonix, the import for the subclass header would be done inside of the .m file not inside of the .h file, so importing the subclass would't import these protected methods.

Comment: Cool Suggestion Brian, thanks a ton !! To the original poster, for declared properties, just ensure that you use @dynamic in the subclass's class extension (unnamed category) implementation, so that at runtime, the parent class's implementation would be used

Comment: How do I see UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h?

Comment: In Xcode, the easiest way is to use "Open Quickly" (⌘O) and then type UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h.

Comment: why does the class use `@interface UIGestureRecognizer (ForSubclassEyesOnly)` instead of just `@interface UIGestureRecognizer ()`? Is that basically just another private interface?

Comment: The empty parentheses indicate a class continuation, rather than a category. Class continuations are special in that you can define properties to be synthesized. These have to be in the same files as the implementation, otherwise they're treated as categories.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about how Apple does it internally. I [posted a full example](http://bootstragram.com/blog/simulating-protected-modifier-with-objective-c/) of how to implement stuff the same way Apple does in `UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h`

Comment: Thank you Henry !!

Answer (score 14):

Here is what I did to get protected methods visible to my subclasses, without requiring them to implement the methods themselves. This meant I didn't get compiler warnings in my subclass about having an incomplete implementation.

SuperClassProtectedMethods.h (protocol file):

```
@protocol SuperClassProtectedMethods <NSObject>
- (void) protectMethod:(NSObject *)foo;
@end

@interface SuperClass (ProtectedMethods) < SuperClassProtectedMethods >
@end
```

SuperClass.m: (compiler will now force you to add protected methods)

```
#import "SuperClassProtectedMethods.h"
@implementation SuperClass
- (void) protectedMethod:(NSObject *)foo {}
@end
```

SubClass.m:

```
#import "SuperClassProtectedMethods.h"
// Subclass can now call the protected methods, but no external classes importing .h files will be able to see the protected methods.
```

Comment: The meaning of *protected* is it is **not able** to be called externally. You still can call any methods defined in the class regardless of they are externally visible or not.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. This method works for the human brain, not actual compiled code. But Objective-C doesn't allow that (not being able to call externally). You can always `performSelector` on it.

Comment: You also can do `[(id)obj hiddenMethod]`. Accurately saying, protected method is not supported in Objective-C.

Comment: The problem with this is that your so called protected classes cannot ad properties. If you do not need properties, then anyone is well aware that you can simply add protected categories.

Comment: @eonil:
"You also can do [(id)obj hiddenMethod]."
Yes, you can do that, but you will get a warning from the compiler, if that method isn't in any included interface.

Comment: So this basically fulfills the purpose of the protected keyword:
The compiler is telling the programmer of some unrelated class, that he is not supposed to use that method, so that programmer knows that when he actively ignores that warning, he is using undefined behavior and is relying on implementation details that could change without notice.
If he then still insists to use that method, we also couldn't stop him in C++, where he could just do some hack like #define protected public before including the header of a class to access its protected methods from a non-subclass.

Comment: @Kaiserludi (1) Formally, Objective-C doesn't have method access control. (2) Inferred from Objective-C instance variable scope keyword, *protected* means access to the member is **allowed only to its subclasses**. With the method described in this answer, **any class** is allowed to access the method by importing the header. This cannot prohibit access from non-subclasses.

Comment: Of course, we can control `#import` manually, but that's just a manual control, not a *protected* method which means to be checked by compiler *over inheritance hierarchy*. This technique can be called *optional*, *hidden* or whatever, but not *protected* which is well-defined term. Because we cannot control importing header only to subclasses. (3) Abusing meta-programming feature to override language keyword semantics is different story just like a memory hack.

Answer (score 10):

I just discovered this and it works for me.To improve upon Adam's answer, in your superclass make an implementation of the protected method in .m file but don't declare it in .h file. In your subclass make a new category in your .m file with the declaration of the protected method of the superclass and you can use the protected method of the superclass in your subclass. This will not ultimately prevent the caller of the supposedly protected method if forced at runtime.

```
/////// SuperClass.h
@interface SuperClass

@end

/////// SuperClass.m
@implementation SuperClass
- (void) protectedMethod
{}
@end

/////// SubClass.h
@interface SubClass : SuperClass
@end

/////// SubClass.m
@interface SubClass (Protected)
- (void) protectedMethod ;
@end

@implementation SubClass
- (void) callerOfProtectedMethod
{
  [self protectedMethod] ; // this will not generate warning
} 
@end
```

Comment: In this case compiler still throw warning about unimplemented method `protectedMethod`

Comment: This is a good work around but instead of making a category (Protected), you can make an extension.

Comment: @skywinder Maybe it did in an earlier version, but the current versions of Xcode have no problem with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using @protected variables.

```
@interface SuperClass:NSObject{
  @protected
    SEL protectedMehodSelector;
}

- (void) hackIt;
@end

@implementation SuperClass

-(id)init{

self = [super init];
if(self) {
 protectedMethodSelector = @selector(baseHandling);
 }

return self;
}

- (void) baseHandling {

  // execute your code here
}

-(void) hackIt {

  [self performSelector: protectedMethodSelector];
}

@end

@interface SubClass:SuperClass
@end

@implementation SubClass

-(id)init{

self = [super init];
if(self) {
 protectedMethodSelector = @selector(customHandling);
 }

return self;
}

- (void) customHandling {

  // execute your custom code here
}

@end
```

Comment: and you can put the protected IVars in a class extension in a header file named protected too

Answer (score 1):

You can define the method as a private method of the parent class and can use `[super performSelector:@selector(privateMethod)];` in the child class.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use *class extension* to hide methods.

In `.h`:

```
@interface SomeAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

In `.m`:

```
@interface SomeAppDelegate()
- (void)localMethod;
@end

@implementation SomeAppDelegate

- (void)localMethod
{
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't think you even need the `@interface` declaration in the .m file. You can just declare a function and use it and it will treat is as private.

Comment: Note that this is true only with the recent updates in Objective C. Prior to that, you had to declare the method in an interface otherwise you'd at least get a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can **sort of** do this with a category.

```
@interface SomeClass (Protected)
-(void)doMadProtectedThings;
@end

@implementation SomeClass (Protected)

- (void)doMadProtectedThings{
    NSLog(@"As long as the .h isn't imported into a class of completely different family, these methods will never be seen. You have to import this header into the subclasses of the super instance though.");
}

@end
```

The methods aren't hidden if you import the category in another class, but you just don't. Due to the dynamic nature of Objective-C it's actually impossible to completely hide a method regardless of a calling instance type.

The best way to go is probably the class continuation category as answered by @Brian Westphal but you'll have to redefine the method in this category for each subclassed instance.

Answer (score 0):

I usually name protected method with internal prefix:

```
-(void) internalMethod;
```