# Objective-C equivalent of Java "protected" modifier

Tags: java, objective-c, protected, access-modifiers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Protected methods in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725857/protected-methods-in-objective-c)

I am a Java developer who is starting to have questions about Objective-C coding syntax.

As of right now, I only see `+/-` that denotes the Java `public/private` equivalents.

How would you implement a protected method in Objective-C?

Comment: You can only specify `@protected`, `@private` for attributes; not methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+`/`-` indicates whether a method is a class method or an instance method -- *not* whether it is public or private.

In short, you can't declare a method as protected in Objective-C. Essentially every method is public, although if you don't declare a method in the header file, it is, in effect, private.